# open all traffic on the pptp interface iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ubuntu-14.04, pptp-client

I set up a PPTP client in Ubuntu. Filter iptables denies network access to everything except TOR and PPTP client.

```
 *filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner debian-tor -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i pptp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -i pptp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

As a result, I receive an error

```
Can't use -i with OUTPUT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly what the error message says. The interface option is not valid in the output chain. Read The Fine Manual: ***-i** "Name of an interface via which a packet was received (only for packets entering the INPUT, FORWARD and PREROUTING chains).*

Comment: Are you sure the name of the interface is `pptp` and not something like `ppp0`?

Answer (score 1):

The `-i` option is to specify an input interface. Obviously it's nonsense in the OUTPUT chain. Use the `-o` option instead.